# Get min/max POINTs from a POLYGON object

Tags: mysql, spatial, mysql-spatial

I have a table with a `geom` column containing polygons.  e.g.:

```
POLYGON((-104.98075 25.83706,-84.659531 25.83706,-84.659531 49.38449,-104.98075 49.38449,-104.98075 25.83706)),4326
```

How can I extract the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude values from that object, as floats?  The idea would be to create `minLat`, `maxLat`, etc., columns in the DB to make searching a bit quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using ST_Envelope(poly)

```
select ST_Envelope(poly) from table WHERE id=1;
```

This returns a polygon with the corners of the contained polygon.

```
POLYGON((
-90.79440777754286 14.37717780192112,
-90.78941725049431 14.37717780192112,
-90.78941725049431 14.3808399138696,
-90.79440777754286 14.3808399138696,
-90.79440777754286 14.37717780192112))
```

Comment: This only returns another polygon which still needs parsed somehow to extract the min and max of the lat and lon as floats